# AVPlayer add Button

Tags: ios, swift, avkit

At the moment I try to add a Button to an AVPlayer. From the documentation it isn't clear to me how you can do this.

Here is an example what I mean:

[image: Apple Developer App example]

The apple developer app has this copy button. But it isn't clear to me how to add one by reading just the documentation. It is clearly an AVPlayer and not a custom controller implementation, because a vanilla player looks nearly the same:

[image: My AVPlayerView]

Any idea how I can archive this without implementing a controller ui by myself? I just want to add a way to adjust video quality without reinventing the wheel.

I was able to place a button there, but I was not able to resize it:

[image: My try]

This is roughly how I did it:

```
// uiViewController -> AVPlayerViewController
    
// self.child -> A SwiftUI view

let childViewController = SelfSizingHostingController(rootView: self.child)
                
childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

childViewController.view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


if let avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView = uiViewController.view.subviews.first?.subviews[1].subviews[4], let parentVC = avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.parentViewController {
    
    if !avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.subviews.map({ String(describing: type(of: $0.self)) }).contains("AVControlOverflowButton") {
        return
    }
    
    uiViewController.buttonIsAdded = true
    
    // Remove all constraints
    avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.removeConstraints(avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.constraints)
    
    // Save subviews in dictionary for constraints(withVisualFormat:)
    
    var viewDictionary: [String: UIView] = [:]
    
    for view in avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.subviews {
        let className = String(describing: type(of: view.self))
        viewDictionary[className] = view;
    }
    
    viewDictionary["QualitySelectorView"] = childViewController.view;
    
    print("dict: \(viewDictionary.keys.joined(separator: ", "))")
    
    // Add to view
    
    parentVC.addChild(childViewController)
    avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.addSubview(childViewController.view)
    childViewController.didMove(toParent: parentVC)
    
    // Update constraints
    
    avMobileAuxiliaryControlsView.addConstraints( NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|\(viewDictionary.keys.map({ "[\($0)]" }).joined(separator: "-"))", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
}
```

Comment: As stated by Apple: "AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem are nonvisual objects, meaning that on their own they are unable to present an asset’s video onscreen."

What system class are you using to actually display your video? `AVPlayerViewController`? (I'm assuming this is for iOS not Mac OS, but you should add an iOS tag.)

What is the `uiViewController` instance variable in your code, and where does it come from?

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry. I edited the post to clarify both things. Yes, uiViewController is an AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: So you're trying to walk the `AVPlayerViewController`'s view hierarchy and add buttons to it manually? **Don't do that.** Full stop. You should treat any view controller's view hierarchy as private, **especially** system view controllers. The view hierarchy is not part of the view controller's contract, it's not documented, and so it is subject to change at any time without warning. Plus you could be breaking things even in the current version of `AVPlayerViewController` without being aware of it.

Comment: Hm okay. Okay, but is there any other way to get there a button? This was just a desperate solution.

Comment: Probably not, no. Apple gives you what they give you. Reaching into a framework object's view hierarchy is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

What is seen on the pictures above is complete custom playerController. If you want to take hold of current implementation of `AVPlayerViewController` with some features such as interactive dismissal, double-tap, presentation modes etc.. however loosing some of the playback controls, there is an official way for implementing Custom Playback Controls that was presented in  [Apple WWDC 2019 AVKit presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/503/) starting at 8min35sec.  What you need to do:

1. modally present `AVPlayerViewController`
2. set `showsPlaybackControls` to `false`
3. add controls to `contentOverlayView`

For more info check the WWDC video.